# API key not found. Check that com.google.android.geo.API_KEY Error in expo development build

Tags: firebase, google-maps, expo, react-native-maps

I have add the key in app.json but still this error occurs. "API key not found. Check that com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"

I have added the key and SHA-1 in google credentials but still error is not resolved. Please provide the solution.
[image]

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and avoid posting a picture of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rebuild development build through expo with
`eas build --profile development --platform android`
or whatever build you use and try again.

The api key changes aren't updated when you hot reload the app, you need to rebuild it.
I had the same issue and that's how I solved it.
Your app.json seems fine.

Comment: Yes, You are right.

Comment: If you're testing locally, you can also delete the Android app, remove the `android` folder with `rm -rf android`, and then run `npx expo run:android`

Comment: @BrianLi comment helped me.