# How to resolve Google Maps API key error on Expo Development Build for Android? API key not found. Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.andr

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am developing a React Native app using Expo (v49). When I run the app on an Android Development Build (not on Expo Go), I encounter the following error: API key not found. Check that  is in AndroidManifest.xml.

Here's how my app.config.js is configured:

```
export default {
  expo: {
    name: 'demo',
    slug: 'demo',
    scheme: 'demo',
    version: '1.0.1',
    orientation: 'portrait',
    icon: './assets/splash.png',
    userInterfaceStyle: 'light',
    runtimeVersion: {
      policy: 'sdkVersion'
    },
    splash: {
      image: './assets/splash.png',
      resizeMode: 'contain',
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    assetBundlePatterns: [
      '**/*'
    ],
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: 'demo'
      }
    },
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: 'demo',
      config: {
        googleMapsApiKey: 'demo'
      },
      associatedDomains: ['applinks:demo.dev'],
      buildNumber: dayjs().format('YYYYMMDDHHmm')
    },
    android: {
      package: 'demo',
      googleServicesFile: './google-services.json',
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: './assets/splash.png',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
      },
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: 'demo'
        }
      },
      intentFilters: [
        {
          action: 'VIEW',
          autoVerify: true,
          data: [
            {
              scheme: 'https',
              host: 'demo.dev',
              pathPrefix: '/demo'
            }
          ],
          category: ['BROWSABLE', 'DEFAULT']
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am also unsure if I need to switch googleServicesFile: './google-services.json', using process.env.APP_VARIANT === 'development'.

Additionally, following the approach described in this article(https://zenn.dev/laiso/articles/6a0b7c94c00248), I attempted to export the google-services.json file in base64 format but it didn't resolve the error.

Furthermore, I attempted to rebuild using eas build --profile development --platform android and also tried following the solutions provided in this Stack Overflow question([API key not found. Check that com.google.android.geo.API_KEY Error in expo development build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76429944/api-key-not-found-check-that-com-google-android-geo-api-key-error-in-expo-devel)), but none of these resolved the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this error. Are there any settings I should check or modify?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can you share the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I don't see AndroidManifest.xml file. Is it because of Expo?

Comment: Probably. Are you using react-native-maps?

Comment: Yes."react-native-maps": "1.7.1"

Comment: Have you done all the steps detailed in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/) from Expo?

Answer (score 0):

It's working since using `yarn dev` but not `yarn dev -clean`. Thank you.